# Hide vim’s backups with a dot in the begining of the backup file name

Tags: vim, backup, dotfiles

I have the following line on my `~/.vimrc`

```
set backup
```

So, every time I edit a file `foo` with vim, a backup file `foo~` is created. Then the output of `ls` is polluted.

I want vim to make the backup’s name began by a dot `.`. Then the backups will be hidden.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible to edit the name of the backup (or even the swap) file. Because latter vim needs to know each backup belongs to each file.

But you can configure a backup directory. You will have one fixed directory adding the following lines to your .vimrc:

```
" Store swap files in fixed location, not current directory.<br/>
set dir=~/.vimswap//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//,.
```

There's also methods to create a backup directory relative to file path. It's a little more complicated, and you can find how to in the following source:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory

Comment: It isn’t exactly what I was searching but it’s an pretty idea as a fall-back.
It isn’t a problem for vim to find witch backup is belonging to each file. vim have only to dell the first dot and the last tilde *~* to know the original file. If we have two files `foo` and `.foo`, theirs backups will be named `.foo~` and `..foo~`.